# JQuery ajax display serverside error (PHP)

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I want to modify the following code so that in the event of a server error, the JS can pop up the returned HTML error created by PHP.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax.php', dataType: 'json',
    data: myData,
    success: function(json){ /**response handler**/}, error: ajaxFail
});
```

At the moment, I'm using firebug to see the returned error html, but it's far from readable. At the moment, when an error occurs, the function ajaxFail receives the error:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character.

How can I have it call a function which displays the html response in the browser in the event there's an error?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know..maybe try `$('ele').append(response)` inside the function, where `function ajaxFail(response)`.

Comment: it may be because You're not parsing a string

Comment: Why not change the default accepted datatype to html so that you can parse it correctly there, and still use the `success` function and turn it in to a json object.  Either that, or register an 'error handler' within PHP and output the results of it for JSON so that your JQuery code and decode it properly?

Comment: Thank you for your responses. (The negative rating, however, is totally uncalled for! Save your anal retentiveness.)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer trawling through the JQuery reference. The first argument passed to error handling function includes the response text.

> The jQuery XMLHttpRequest (jqXHR) object returned by $.ajax() as of
>   jQuery 1.5 is a superset of the browser's native XMLHttpRequest
>   object.

And the function spec:

> error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)

So to access it, in the error function I read jqXHR.responseText. I had only been using the errorThrown, as it was someone else's code doing the error handling.